# Python Script to convert multiple json files in to single csv

Tags: python, json, xlsx, converters

```
{
  "type": "Data",
  "version": "1.0",
  "box": {
    "identifier": "abcdef",
    "serial": "12345678"
  },
  "payload": {
    "Type": "EL",
    "Version": "1",
    "Result": "Successful",
    "Reference": null,
    "Box": {
      "Identifier": "abcdef",
      "Serial": "12345678"
    },
    "Configuration": {
      "EL": "1"
    },
    "vent": [
      {
        "ventType": "Arm",
        "Timestamp": "2020-03-18T12:17:04+10:00",
        "Parameters": [
          {
            "Name": "Arm",
            "Value": "LT"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Status",
            "Value": "LD"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ventType": "Arm",
        "Timestamp": "2020-03-18T12:17:24+10:00",
        "Parameters": [
          {
            "Name": "Arm",
            "Value": "LT"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Status",
            "Value": "LD"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "EventType": "TimeUpdateCompleted",
        "Timestamp": "2020-03-18T02:23:21.2979668Z",
        "Parameters": [
          {
            "Name": "ActualAdjustment",
            "Value": "PT0S"
          },
          {
            "Name": "CorrectionOffset",
            "Value": "PT0S"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Latency",
            "Value": "PT0.2423996S"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please describe more details :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to precisely define your question, showing your input and expected output. If possible, show us what you have tried so far and explain why it doesn't work. Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to formulate a good question likely to get help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to transfer information from a JSON file to a CSV, then you can use the following code to read in a JSON file into a dictionary in Python:

```
import json

with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data_dict = json.load(json_file)
```

You could then convert this dictionary into a list with either `data_dict.items()` or `data_dict.values()`.

Then you just need to write this list to a CSV file which you can easily do by just looping through the list.

Comment: box__serial payload__Type payload__Version payload__Result payload__Reference payload__Box__Identifier payload__Box__Serial payload__Configuration__EL payload__vent__ventType payload__vent__Timestamp payload__vent__Parameters__Name payload__vent__Parameters__Value
These are the columns I'm looking for the xlsx files..thanks